# Update Datetime null value to not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column DateTime datatype with default value null .

I am using following code to update the Datetime to proper datetime , but it is not working .

My code as below

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = GETDATE()

update Testing set SomeDate = @SomeDate  where  SomeDate  <> @SomeDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = GETDATE()

update Testingset 
set SomeDate = @SomeDate  
where  SomeDate  is null
or SomeDate  <> @SomeDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Testingset
   SET SomeDate = @SomeDate
 WHERE SomeDate IS NULL
    OR SomeDate != @SomeDate
```

Comment: Hi , I want to make sure the statement run only when the value is different or null

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your code is not doing what you want.  And your code should be:

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = GETDATE();

update Testingset
    set SomeDate = @SomeDate 
    where SomeDate is null;
```

There is no apparent reason for using a variable.  You might as well do:

```
update Testingset
    set SomeDate = getdate()
    where SomeDate is null;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you seem to want:

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = GETDATE();

update Testingset
    set SomeDate = @SomeDate 
    where SomeDate is null or SomeDate <> @SomeDate;
```

Comment: Hi , I want to make sure the statement run only when the value is different or null

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following would accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
UPDATE Testing
   SET SomeDate = getdate()
 WHERE SomeDate IS NULL
    OR SomeDate <> getdate();
```

You might do better to use the ANSI standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` over `getdate()`:

```
UPDATE Testing
   SET SomeDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 WHERE SomeDate IS NULL
    OR SomeDate <> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: The OR here is really kind of meaningless unless you happen to have a row with the EXACT value as getdate() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: That's true, I wasn't thinking. One may as well eliminate the entire `WHERE` clause.